# Blocks in margin layout in HTML and CSS

Tags: html, css

My web page is a discussion of another document, page by page. I want to follow the structure of the original document (with headings, sub headings and paragraphs), but also have the page number (or page ranges) appear in a 120px margin, just to the left of the first paragraph on that page(s) that I am discussing.

So far, I have roughly what I want. The main discussion is inside a DIV tag, with the "description". The page number marginalia is kept inside a DIV tag with the class "page".

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; CHARSET=windows-1251">
        <TITLE>Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble</TITLE>
        <STYLE>
        DIV.page            { border-style: solid; border-width:medium; float:left; position:relative; left:-100px; width:70px; padding:2px; }
        DIV.description     { position:relative; left:100px; }
        </STYLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000" LINK="#FF0000" VLINK="#800000" ALINK="#FF00FF">
        <H1>Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble</H1>
        <DIV CLASS="description">
            <H2>Blurble Blurble</H2>
            <P>
            Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble .
            </P>
            <P>
            Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble .
            </P>
            <H2>Blurble Blurble</H2>
            <DIV CLASS="page">Blurble 1</DIV>
            <P>
            Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble.
            </P>
            <P>
            Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble .
            </P>
            <H2>Blurble Blurble</H2>
            <DIV CLASS="page">Blurble 2</DIV>
            <P>
            Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble.
            </P>
            <P>
            Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble Blurble .
            </P>
        </DIV>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

The problem here is that wherever the page DIV appears, there is a gap between that DIV element and a portion of the P element - a chunk of whitespace. It seems as if the browser thinks that the page DIV element should be sitting in that space, so it is wrapping the text around where it thinks the DIV element should be.

Add to that, the browser always should the horizontal scroll bar to scroll through the extra 100px of extra space it thinks it should add to the window.

Comment: Could you provide a jsfiddle of your code so we are able to see the reported problem?

Comment: I had never heard of jsfiddle until now :-) Anyhow, I am posting a full HTML example above.

Comment: jsfiddle is a very resourceful tool for other people to view your code/markup to see the problem. It will definitely become handy in the future for any questions which may come up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty sure that you have to change your .page class' position attribute to absolute.

Comment: Bloody hell - that worked! I don't suppose you can tell me how to stop the horizontal scrolling?

Comment: Hmmm. I seem to have fixed this by adding: DIV.description { margin-right:100px; } !!

Comment: The horizontal scrolling happens because of the positioning. The <div> tag is a block-level element, meaning it's width is inherited by it's parent element, in this case, the <body> tag, set to 100%.

By positioning this element and pushing it to the right by a 100 pixels, the scroll bar appears, since the browser does not reduce the width of the element.

Either use margin, as you said, or play around with the width of the elements. Both works.